# Implementing Authentication, Resource, and Client Server Functionalities in a Spring Boot Monolith: Any Issues?

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I am currently developing a Spring Boot monolithic server and planning to implement authentication and authorization processes using Spring Security. I have studied OAuth2 and seen examples where the authentication server, resource server, and client server are developed separately.

Can these three server functionalities be implemented simultaneously within a monolithic server? Would such a structure pose any problems?

Answer (score 0):

Usually in OAuth you separate concerns to enable future growth:

**RESOURCE SERVERS**

These provide backend business functionality and you might have many of them, eg:

- Customers API
- Orders API
- Business API

**FRONTEND APPS**

It is also common to build frontend apps that provide a great customer experience, eg:

- A React app
- An Android app
- An iOS app

The client is usually the frontend app, though a web client like a React app should use a backend component as the OAuth client, for best security.

By using APIs all of these frontends have access to the same backend logic.

**AUTHORIZATION SERVER**

I interpreted your question as implementing this in your resource server. It is possible I misunderstood.

The AS provides low level security. You only have one of these and it serves all of the above components. Think of it a specialist API that you plug in. The AS issues tokens to secure APIs and enables many ways to authenticate users.

**DESIGN YOUR SETUP**

You can develop a single monolothic app if you prefer, but the AS should definitely be separate. This will save you a lot of time since a good AS with correct support for standards takes multiple years to develop. To get started on OAuth development, [my blog post](https://authguidance.com/oauth-infrastructure-setup/) might give you some ideas.

Comment: No, single page apps (Angular, React, Vue, etc.) should not be configured as OAuth2 clients. These can only be public clients, when it is recommended to use only confidential clients (in the case of a SPA, a BFF running on the server is probably the best option for an OAuth2 client). https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/297#issue-896744390

Comment: A pure SPA can be a confidential client if it calls a utility API that serves as a BFF, as in [this example](https://curity.io/resources/learn/financial-grade-oauth-agent/) we provided at Curity. This link is unrelated to H-D's question though.

Comment: In the diagram of the article you link, what is the OAuth2 client is called "OAuth2 Agent" and is running on the server, it is not the SPA in the browser. The code running user devices (single page or mobile apps) can't keep a secret and as so are necessarily public clients. The link with the question is it mentions explicitly the "client" according to OAuth2 definition (and again, this should not be a frontend running on user device)

Comment: Ah - technically the BFF is the OAuth client - you are right that it is more accurate to say that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. All you have to do is to define a `SecurityFilterChain` bean for each actor. When having more than one filter-chain, all must be decorated with a different `@Order` and all but the one with highest order (lowest precedence) must contain a security-matcher to intercept only the requests it should process.

But you should probably not:

- OAuth2 is definitely not designed for monolithic apps (form-login which is used on authorization servers is probably more adapted)
- picking an Authorization server like Keycloak or a cloud offer like Auth0 would save you a lot of time compared to building one with spring-authorization-server (not a years diff, but still noticeable)
- using a different process for each actor in your architecture will help you better grasp interactions (OAuth2 client, OAuth2 resource server, OAuth2 authorization server, and stuff like maybe frontend, reverse-proxy, etc.)